# blow out / blow off / blow away

Tags: prepositional-phrases

What prepositions should I use in here:

> I wiped with eraser what he had drawn with a pencil on paper and blew out the garbage on him.

1. Blew out / away / off the garbage "on" / or "in" him?

Comment: We don't wipe with an eraser, just use erase as a verb, "I *erased* what he had drawn..."

Answer (score 3):

I erased what he had drawn in pencil and blew the crumbs onto him.

P.S. Sometimes they're called *eraser-crumbs*.